# Why is it recommended that I replace tabs by spaces?

Tags: python

I have read in some python tutorials that it's better to use spaces than tabs.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: Why was this question closed as "primarily opinion-based" instead of as a duplicate? From the on hold explanation - *"... answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."* In fact, the correct answers **are** based on specific facts and references - PEP8. Maybe I think about these things a little more because I just recently got close vote rights, but don't be so quick to pick the closure reason everyone else is picking, just because everyone else is picking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's the community standard.

Guido Van Rossum actually [preferr{s,ed} tabs](http://web.archive.org/web/20160513172920/http://legacy.python.org/search/hypermail/python-1994q2/0205.html), but the community as a whole prefers spaces. If you want to share code, standards are especially helpful.

That's it. There are advantages to both spaces and tabs, but sticking to the standard tends to outweigh both.

Some advantages of spaces:

- Spaces are less often mangled by badly-designed software
- Some align code in ways that no longer work when you use tabs
- The indentation is more consistent if you move code between editors that have different tabstops

etc.

Comment: I've seen people say that he prefers tabs in lots of places, but not ever any link to any source…

Comment: @kyrias Although I haven't kept a source, and memory can be faulty, I will say that this is a first-hand account. I did read Guido say this somewhere in the archives, as far as I can recall. Sorry that I don't have an actual source.

Comment: @kyrias FWIW, there are twice as many tabs in the Python 1.5 source as there are four-space indents.

Comment: @kyrias http://legacy.python.org/search/hypermail/python-1994q2/0205.html

Comment: @RNikoopour: Cool thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the PEP 008 style guidelines.

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

And I will make a direct quote to answer your question.

```
One of Guido's key insights is that code is read much more often than it is 
written. The guidelines provided here are intended to improve the readability of 
code and make it consistent across the wide spectrum of Python code. As PEP 20 
says, "Readability counts".
```

Comment: I'd really love it if whoever downvoted me would care to explain what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: The PEP 008 style guidelines say "This document gives coding conventions for the Python code **comprising the standard library in the main Python distribution**" (emphasis added). This guideline is meant specifically for the standard library, not for all Python code ever written.

Answer (score 3):

Uniformness.

Also, tabs can be multiple lengths (visually) whereas a space is always a space.

Check out [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more info about Python Style.

Answer (score 3):

Because python is whitespace sensitive -  if a line has four spaces and the next has one tab, python will NOT see them as being indented the same, giving you either compile errors, or even worse, code that executes in a way that you don't want.  Because they look the same to you, you will not be able to tell the difference easily.

So set your editor to not use tabs, so that you can trust your eyes.

Comment: Switch "tabs" and "spaces" and the same argument applies. This doesn't make much sense, especially if you have a good editor.

Comment: It's embarrassing how this answer has 4 upvotes when its completely wrong and every other answer has 0 or -1 scores when they're completely right.

Comment: This answer is in fact correct. Python sees tabs as equivalent to 8 spaces. So if you have tab stops set to 4 in your editor, such that the line indented 4 spaces and the line indented 1 tab look like they line up, *they do not line up as far as Python is concerned.*

Comment: @kindall read Veedrac's comment. "Switch tabs to spaces and the same argument applies", but the thing is we follow PEP8 style guidelines. That is why we use 4 spaces instead of all tabs. I was not suggesting using a mixture of tabs and spaces at all. I was only saying that this doesn't explain why it's recommended to use 4 spaces over 1 tab. (The only explanation for that is PEP8/uniformity with Python's style guidelines)